# How can I block a certain character from entering in a input field in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to block "-" (dash) from entering into the input field by the user. The "-" code is 189.

Here's my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"

interface Props {
  value: string
}

function InputFormat(props: Props) {
  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(() => value)

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setStateValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const handlekeyDown = (event: any) => {
    if (event.keycode === 189) {
      return
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        onKeyDown={(e) => handlekeyDown(e)}
        value={stateValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default InputFormat
```

This is not working as expected. I am trying to `return` if the keycode is 189 form dash, but still I'm able to type. How can I achieve this here (notice this is a controlled component).

Comment: what's the use case?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)s do not have a `keycode`. They have a deprecated [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) (will be removed at some point).

Possible replacements for your check:

- `event.key === '-'`
- `['Minus', 'NumpadSubtract'].includes(event.code)`

Secondly, to prevent the change in `<input />`'s value, you have to call `preventDefault()` method on `event`:

```js
const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) =>
  event.key === "-" && event.preventDefault()
```

---

Side note: preventing default on user input is considered detrimental UX. The user does not feel respected. Disabling keyboard user input in `<input/>`s has been demonstrated to increase bounce rate and decrease user loyalty of web-pages.

A more respectful way of telling them they're not allowed particular values in `<input />` is to display an invalidity message about the current value, coupled with some visual indicator (red border, etc...). Or, as @DanielBeck pointed out in the comments, to simply disregard the dash where you're consuming it (without overriding the user input's value).

Comment: Excellent point regarding the UX decisions here.  Another suggestion might be to change whatever receives this value to work correctly whether the user includes the '-' or not...

Answer (score 0):

Check `event.key` (`keyCode` is deprecated) and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the character from being entered.

```js
const handlekeyDown = (event) => {
  if (event.key === '-') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could return if the value is `-` in your `handleChange` function.

```
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    if(event.target.value == '-') {
      return;
    }
    setStateValue(event.target.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listening keyDown and use preventDefault it is not the best way.

A more attractive solution is move condition to onChange:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"

interface Props {
  value: string
}

function InputFormat(props: Props) {
  const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(() => value)
  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.includes('-')) return
    setValue(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={stateValue}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default InputFormat
```

The best solution it will be if you modify this code with regex. It would be much more scalable.

```
const noDashesRegex = /[-]+/
```

```
if (noDashesRegex.test(e.target.value)) return
```

Comment: OP asked for new dashes to be prevented, not to remove all existing dashes.

Comment: ok, this solution easy to change and add condition to pass default previous value and dont check it. But i still think that use keyDown listening it's bad practice. If OP really need this condition - no problem to present it.

Comment: Could you present any argument or documentation to demonstrate `keyDown` listening is bad practice? Who told you this?

Comment: Of course there is no specification that prohibits this but such solutions always end with one. If you want change condition or add something more - you have to and more and more codes of key. And sooner or later someone will have to refactoring this code to regex. Or you think libs for forms uses codes for validate user input?

Comment: [SO] does not welcome opinionated answers. Please base your answers on facts, not opinions. Another hazardous claim in your answer is that using regex increases scalability. I'd be inclined to believe the opposite. One thing I know for sure is that replacing input value while the user is typing increases the bounce rate of any page and, ultimately, it is losing that website money.

Comment: Hm. You want to add some symbols to validation. With code of key you have to change your component, add new conditions. With regexp you just edit your config. I think this is fact, not opinion. Ok, you didnt agree with me and I didint agree with you. OP is our judge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251875/discussion-between-tao-and-rycha).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd either use a regular expression or just includes(), but
if you insist on using a keycode, you just convert the character to a keycode, and if any of the characters within your input string match your key code, then return, else, update your state:

Code sandbox example, but I'm testing for "e" instead of the dash:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-forest-7qxlub?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [field, setField] = useState("");

  const sanitizeInput = (e) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.value.length; i++) {
      let code = e.target.value.charCodeAt(i) - 32;
      if (code === 69) {
        return;
      }
    }
    setField(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <input value={field} onChange={(e) => sanitizeInput(e)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```